# Interim analysis: probability of stopping

Tags: p-value, survival, combining-p-values

Say we do some time-varying study. We check yearly if early stopping is necessary, which is done via interim analysis (O'Brien-Fleming stopping boundaries). The 4 p-values for stopping in 4 consecutive years are: 5e-6, 0.001, 0.009 and 0.02.

Now the question is the following:

*If the null hypothesis is true and if the 4 test statistics were independent, what
would then be the probability of stopping on (at least) one of these time points?*

How should I calculate this probability of stopping? I'm pretty confused here, since p-value only reflects the probability of getting a more extreme value for the test statistic than the current one. I don't see the link with 'probability of stopping the study'. Does this depend on the significance level?

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about it for a while, I think the answer is relatively easy. It does depend on the sigfnicance level. Say the significance level is 5% for each test, than the total probability of stopping the study would be $1- (1-0.05)^4$.